# How to return counted edges using a Match statement?

Tags: graph, match, orientdb, graph-databases, depth

I'm running this query to iterate over a graph in OrientDB.

```
 MATCH {class: M ,as :n, where: (p = '561')}.both("R")
          {as: r, while: ($depth < 1)} RETURN  r ,n
```

I assume that `r` is the number of the vertices. How do I return the number of the edges?

Answer (score 1):

First observation: you can omit `while: ($depth < 1)`, as the MATCH statement by default just traverses one single level.

I'm not sure what you exactly need, but if you need the number of edges connected to n, you can do `RETURN r, n, r.both("R").size()` as numOfEdges